# How to update React Native ListView when Realm data changes

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a list of 'Activity' objects stored in a Realm DB which are showing on a ListView. 
There is no problem initially loading the data and showing it on the screen. However, when the data update (in another screen, lets call it 'detail edit screen') and the user returns to the list screen, the list isn't updated.

I tried to setState inside the render method, but that returns a blank screen.

```
    var activities = realm.objects('Activity').sorted('date');
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}); 
    ...
    module.exports = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function(){
        return { 
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(activities),
        };
      },
    ...
    render: function(){
       //update the list of activities
        activities = realm.objects('Activity').sorted('date'); 
        this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(activities)});
         return ( 
          <View>
              {(!activities || activities.length<1) && noActivitiesMessage}
                  <ListView style={styles.listStyle} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
            renderRow={this._renderRow} />
    </View>

)
...
}
```

Comment: Are you using ListView from Realm or React Native core?

Comment: I tried it with both. Using Realm's ListView crashes the app, if I try to update the state in render() as shown above. It shows the error: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem like you. My problem was solve by using the Realm ListView. I use it like this

```
import { ListView } from 'realm/react-native';

class List extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    src = realm.objects('MyObject');
    this.setState({
      dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(src),
      data:src
    });
  } 

  updateData(){
   // update or add object in Realm
   this.setState({
     dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.data)
   });
  } 

  render(){
    return( 
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow=... />
  }
}
```

Comment: I my app when I click on a list item it open a new screen (a form) and I pass updateData to this form by props. When I valid the form it call this.prop.updateData(data) next I update my data in realm and do the setState. Sorry I don't add it in the previous sample.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the [`react-native-realm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-realm) package on NPM (full disclosure, I'm the author, so I'm a little biased). It uses the provider pattern (similar to react-redux) to provide realm data and automatic change event listening (as well as automatic removal of those event listeners) to your components by simply wrapping them in the `connectRealm` higher order component and defining which schemas and where to map them in the props of your component.

You could use it like this. In the top level component of your app wrap the sub components with `RealmProvider`.

```
// App.js

// the file you use to wire up your realm schemas, etc.
import realm from './path/to/your/realm/file';
import { RealmProvider } from 'react-native-realm';
import List from './List';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    <RealmProvider realm={realm}>
      <List />
    </RealmProvider>
  }

export default App;
```

And then in your sub components if they need realm data use the `connectRealm` function to hook into that data.

```
// List.js

import { ListView } from 'realm/react-native';
import { connectRealm } from 'react-native-realm';

class List extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      }).cloneWithRows(props.activities);
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(nextProps.activities),
    });
  } 

  render(){
    return ( 
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow=... 
      />
    )
  }
}

export default connectRealm(List, {
  schemas: ['Activity'],
  mapToProps({ activities }) {
    return {
      activities: activities.sorted('date'), // do extra filtering and sorting here
    };
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned in your comment, `setState` may not be called in the render function (it would basically cause an infinite recursion).

The easiest solution here is to add a listener in the constructor, which would look like this for your example:

```
realm.addListener('change', () => {
    this.setState({dataSource: realm.objects('Activity').sorted('date'); })
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much; banged my head the whole week trying to track my Realm changes

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach, thanks to @Johannes's answer and @tiby's suggestion to use realm's listview.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      ds: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged (a, b) {
          return a.done !== b.done || a.text !== b.text || a.items || b.items
        }
      }),
      src: realm.objects(‘Object’),
    }

    realm.addListener('change', () => {
        this.setState({src: realm.objects(‘Object’) })
    });
}

render () {
    var dataSource = this.state.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.src)
    return (
        <ListView
          dataSource={dataSource}
          …
        />
   )
}
```