# Realm React Native ListView not updating

Tags: listview, react-native, realm

I am trying to render a list of realm objects that are nested within another.  Consider this schema:

```
const ThingSchema = {
   name: 'Thing',
   properties: {
      stuff: { type: 'list', objectType: 'Stuff' }
   }
}
```

Now I've created a datasource as:

```
dataSource.cloneWithRows(thing.stuff)
```

I have a method that makes an api call that downloads a new version of "thing" with an updated "stuff" list after the scene loads.

Since I'm building the ListView DataSource from Realm objects, I would expect that the list would redraw after the api completes and the new version of thing is written to the DB, however, it does not.

If I navigate away from the scene, then back, the new, updated list shows, so I know it is being properly saved.  Also, if I add a listener with realm.addListener and reload "thing" from the DB and call setState[1], the list refreshes.

Will realm not redraw on updated nested objects without a listener?

[1] [How to update React Native ListView when Realm data changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529058/how-to-update-react-native-listview-when-realm-data-changes)

Comment: You might wanna check on this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902361/realm-react-native-best-practice-to-implement-auto-updates/41180674#41180674)

Comment: Even though the realm object will be up to date, React Native has no way of knowing this if you don't use a listener or refresh manually somehow.